# Quantifiers with MaxSMT in z3

Tags: z3, smt

Can we use quantifiers with soft constraints in z3? I get the following message when using them together.

```
WARNING: optimization with quantified constraints is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not supported. This was requested before, you can add your opinion: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1711